# Ввести с клавиатуры множество последователн. симв. из диапазона от А до Я. Определ. число различных (без повтор.)букв, входящих в последовательность

Tags: python, set

```
word = input('Введите последовательность:')
count = 0
alphabet = set("АаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯя")
for letter in word:
    if letter in alphabet:
        count += 1
print('Количество букв равно:')
print(count)
```

Получилось так, что он считает количество всех букв в последовательности, в том числе и с повторениями. Как сделать так, чтобы код выводил сами буквы и их количество?

Comment: так нужно и считать количество разных букв, а не проверять сколько букв являются буквами

Comment: только только учусь,буду признателен, если у вас получится объяснить это кодом

Comment: @Эникейщик я так понял, по заданию нужно сначала определить, какие из символов являются буквами, а потом уже посчитать только их

Comment: Оформите вопрос как полагается. в заголовке краткое изложение сути, в теле вопроса - собственно вопрос. без сокращений.

Answer (score 0):

```
word = input('Введите последовательность:')
alphabet = set("АаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯя")
out = alphabet.intersection(word)

print(f'Количество букв равно: {len(out)}')
print(out)
```

```
Введите последовательность:мама мыла Раму 10 раз
Количество букв равно: 8
{'л', 'а', 'з', 'ы', 'у', 'Р', 'р', 'м'}
```

Выше строчные и прописные (заглавные) буквы считаются разными. Если нужно считать строчные и прописные одинаковыми, то можно так:

```
word = input('Введите последовательность:').lower()
alphabet = set("АаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯя".lower())
out = alphabet.intersection(word)

print(f'Количество букв равно: {len(out)}')
print(out)
```

```
Введите последовательность:мама мыла Раму 10 раз
Количество букв равно: 7
{'з', 'л', 'у', 'ы', 'а', 'м', 'р'}
```

Comment: ну зачем вы опять поощряете лентяев?...

Comment: @Эникейщик мне так не показалось. Как однозначно отличить одних от других?